# Jetpack Compose drawLine with stampedPathEffect

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-canvas

I try to draw a line with a ᐯ shape like this.

[image]

So I first created a `Path` with a ᐯ shape.

```kotlin
val lineWidth = 10.dp.toPx() * 5
val lineHeight = 5.dp.toPx() * 5

val arrowPath =
    Path().apply {
        moveTo(x = 0f, y = 0f)
        lineTo(x = lineWidth / 2f, y = lineHeight)
        lineTo(x = lineWidth, y = 0f)
    }
```

Then I put in a `PathEffect.stampedPathEffect` that uses the ᐯ-shaped `Path` as the `pathEffect` for `drawLine` using `Canvas`.

```kotlin
val strokeWidth = 1.dp.toPx() * 5
val arrowPathEffect =
    PathEffect.stampedPathEffect(
        shape = arrowPath,
        advance = 0f,
        phase = 0f,
        style = StampedPathEffectStyle.Translate,
    )

drawLine(
    color = Color.Black,
    start = Offset(x = size.center.x, y = 0f),
    end = Offset(x = size.center.x, y = size.height / 2),
    strokeWidth = strokeWidth,
    cap = StrokeCap.Round,
    pathEffect = arrowPathEffect,
)
```

However, the result was a plain line drawn with no `stampedPathEffect` applied. To validate the ᐯ-shaped `Path` I created, I drew it by itself using `drawPath` and it drew just as I expected.

[image]

What am I missing in the `drawLine` + `PathEffect` combination?

Full code:

```kotlin
Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    val lineWidth = 10.dp.toPx() * 5
    val lineHeight = 5.dp.toPx() * 5
    val strokeWidth = 1.dp.toPx() * 5

    val arrowPath =
        Path().apply {
            moveTo(x = 0f, y = 0f)
            lineTo(x = lineWidth / 2f, y = lineHeight)
            lineTo(x = lineWidth, y = 0f)
        }
    val arrowPathEffect =
        PathEffect.stampedPathEffect(
            shape = arrowPath,
            advance = 0f,
            phase = 0f,
            style = StampedPathEffectStyle.Translate,
        )

    drawLine(
        color = Color.Black,
        start = Offset(x = size.center.x, y = 0f),
        end = Offset(x = size.center.x, y = size.height / 2),
        strokeWidth = strokeWidth,
        cap = StrokeCap.Round,
        pathEffect = arrowPathEffect,
    )

    translate(left = size.center.x, top = size.height * 0.8f) {
        drawPath(
            path = arrowPath,
            color = Color.Red,
            style = Stroke(width = strokeWidth),
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `advance` param of `PathEffect.stampedPathEffect` to another value other than 0. But this will draw closed shape, i don't know if it's possible to do it without it closing shape. You can draw your outcome in a loop while translating y position on each draw

Comment: @Thracian Oh... you were right about everything. Thank you.